# Chrome Extension internationalization error?

Tags: json, google-chrome, internationalization, google-chrome-extension

When i add `"default_locale": "en",` to my manifest file, then package it and try to upload it, i get the error message saying, `An error occurred: Message JSON file must be in UTF-8 encoding.` ... But this is how they tell you to set it up in their [i18n](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html) page... What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved the issue... After googling awhile... turns out MS notepad is inadequate even with utf-8 encoding... Download "Notepad2"... and set the encoding to utf-8... somehow it works now!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure he's missing the Byte Order Mark -- which is [neither required nor recommended in UTF-8](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (as endianness isn't relevant) -- I think it's just the file encoding. I believe Notepad adds the BOM by default when you save as UTF-8, but I always save files without it as some programs that receive UTF-8 data don't expect the BOM.

But yes, bottom line, go to the file and Save As in UTF-8. If you *are* using Notepad, I'd recommend using a different editor -- for JS something lightweight like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) works well -- so that you can change the default encoding, among many other benefits.

Comment: Thanks for this, i now get a new error message... "An error occurred: Cannot parse message.json file from uploaded package."... this json file translates english characters into chinese characters... It uploads normally without error with normal characters... but not with the chinese versions... need a utf-8 convertor or something? similar to ascii code?

Comment: I had this issue before with [an extension in Japanese](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bhnbpahgjklokfhbaaifmgcjapolomgj?hl=ja), where the solution was to remove any comments from the language json file. Any chance that's the same as your issue? Chrome Web Store's been known to have problems with this even if Chrome functions properly.

Comment: just solved the issue... After googling awhile... turns out MS notepad is inadequate even with utf-8 encoding... Download "Notepad2"... and set the encoding to utf-8... somehow it works now!

Comment: Just as note to everyone, I'm thinking the BOM may actually be _the culprit_ in this case. As I mentioned, Notepad (and other MS text editors) are notable for always having it. Everyone else does the smart thing and either leaves it out by default or offers both options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you simply missing [Byte Order Mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in front of your manifest file. If you are on Windows simply open it in Notepad, click File -> Save As and choose UTF-8 from Encoding combo box.
Obviously you can use other tools to "convert" to UTF-8...