# Is there an Standard format of message.json for Chrome.i18n

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I used Chrome.i18n and wrote several message.json files. And I didn't know which file format should choose for it.  ANSI, UTF-8 or others. And I find most of the chrome extensions chosed ANSI. Is it the standard format for message.json file?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about (are you writing a Chrome extension?) but ANSI is not a real encoding. ANSI means "whatever encoding my computer uses". Additionally, the default character encoding for JSON is UTF8, though it also supports UTF16 and UTF32.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a chrome extension. I want to ask how to write a message.json file for the Chrome.i18n protocol and which encoding should I choosed for the message.json file~?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has to be saved as [UTF-8](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for non-[ASCII](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters (accented letters, Chinese characters, *etc.*) to work. The "ANSI" setting may work if no such characters exist in any of the messages. Do not select [UTF-16](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Text editors often guess character encodings of text files by looking for characteristic patterns of byte values. It is not possible to distinguish [Windows-1252](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or other so-called "ANSI" encodings from UTF-8 in the absence of non-ASCII characters because ASCII is a common subset of both. Your text editor apparently assumes "ANSI", indicating UTF-8 only when non-ASCII characters are actually in use in the Chrome extensions you have seen.

Some text editors (Windows Notepad in particular) add a [byte order mark](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) to any file saved as UTF-8. Although that character allows determining the file's UTF-8 encoding, Google Chrome does not expect to see it and [fails to load the JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342089/chrome-extension-internationalization-error).

If you use Windows Notepad, you ought to switch to [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or another text editor that has an option to save as "UTF-8 without BOM". You also should consider setting up your editor to use UTF-8 by default, even for existing files.